# how can i get details of transactions from any block number without using event?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, blocks

Without using event i want to fetch all the details of how many transaction with transaction id are contained in any specific block by just putting block number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using web3, you can use the function getBlock. Then, you can read the value of "transactions" (an array) from the object received to calculate the number of transactions and their txids:

- [web3.eth.getBlock](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblock)

> Returns a block matching the block number or block hash.

**Example**

```
web3.eth.getBlock(10855106).then(console.log)

/*
{
  "number": 3,
  "hash": "0xef95f2f1ed3ca60b048b4bf67cde2195961e0bba6f70bcbea9a2c4e133e34b46",
  "parentHash": "0x2302e1c0b972d00932deb5dab9eb2982f570597d9d42504c05d9c2147eaf9c88",
  "nonce": "0xfb6e1a62d119228b",
  "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "transactionsRoot": "0x3a1b03875115b79539e5bd33fb00d8f7b7cd61929d5a3c574f507b8acf415bee",
  "stateRoot": "0xf1133199d44695dfa8fd1bcfe424d82854b5cebef75bddd7e40ea94cda515bcb",
  "miner": "0x8888f1f195afa192cfee860698584c030f4c9db1",
  "difficulty": BigNumber,
  "totalDifficulty": BigNumber,
  "size": 616,
  "extraData": "0x",
  "gasLimit": 3141592,
  "gasUsed": 21662,
  "timestamp": 1429287689,
  "transactions": [
    "0x9fc76417374aa880d4449a1f7f31ec597f00b1f6f3dd2d66f4c9c6c445836d8b"
  ],
  "uncles": []
}
*/
```

Comment: If you're running a node you can ask for block data directly from the command line using curl, thus:

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a node locally you can ask for block data directly from the command line using curl, thus:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["0x200100", true],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
```

This works for Parity. Note you have to use hex for the block number.